# Node ORM for Oracle and PostgreSQL

Tags: node.js, node-postgres, node-oracledb, node-orm2

I'm on the look out for a node ORM that works well with both Oracle and PostgreSQL.

I see that Waterline and Sequelize do not have built in support for Oracle.

Sequelize-Oracle is available though.

Is there a single node ORM module that supports both Oracle and PostgreSQL ?

Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

You should use [knaxjs](http://knexjs.org/) to generate query for both Oracle and PostgreSQL. Another way is use [cu8-sequelize-oracle](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cu8-sequelize-oracle) for Oracle and sequelizejs for PostgreSQL. Thanks!